# How do I use GP.fit in sci-kit learn for a multi-dimensional input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian

Is it possible to provide an example? I am trying to use it for a 5D input. Also, how do I plot a chart for each input against the output. I have one output dimension. My idea is to pass some training set data and then validate the output against a testing dataset.
I would like to pass a 5d(X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 input where, I have 1600 data points. Right now I only have X1 as my input

Here is the Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, Matern, WhiteKernel, ConstantKernel, RationalQuadratic, ExpSineSquared, DotProduct
# define Kernel

import numpy as np
kernels = [1.0 * RBF(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-1, 10.0)),
           1.0 * Matern(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-1, 10.0),
                        nu=1.5),
           1.0 * RationalQuadratic(length_scale=1.0, alpha=0.1),
           1.0 * ExpSineSquared(length_scale=1.0, periodicity=3.0,
                                length_scale_bounds=(0.1, 10.0),
                                periodicity_bounds=(1.0, 10.0)),
           ConstantKernel(0.1, (0.01, 10.0))
               * (DotProduct(sigma_0=1.0, sigma_0_bounds=(0.0, 10.0)) ** 2),
           ]

# Define inputs and outputs
x = np.array([-5.2,-3,-2,-1,1,5], ndmin=2).T
X = x.reshape(-1, 1)
y =np.array([-2,0,1,2,-1,1])
max_x = max(x)
min_x = min (x)
max_y = max (y)
min_y = min(y)

for fig_index, kernel in enumerate(kernels):
    # call GP regression library and fit inputs to output
    gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
    gp.fit(X, y)
#     parameter = get_params(deep=True)
#     print(parameter)           

    gp.kernel_
    print(gp.kernel_)
    plt.figure(fig_index, figsize=(10,6))
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    x_pred = np.array(np.linspace(-5, 5,50), ndmin=2).T

    # Mark the observations
    plt.plot(X, y, 'ro', label='observations')

    X_test = np.array(np.linspace(max_x+1, min_x-1, 1000),ndmin=2).T
    y_mean, y_std = gp.predict(X_test, return_std=True)
    # Draw a mean function and 95% confidence interval
    plt.plot(X_test, y_mean, 'b-', label='mean function')
    upper_bound = y_mean +y_std
    lower_bound = y_mean - y_std
    plt.fill_between(X_test.ravel(), lower_bound, upper_bound, color = 'k', alpha = 0.2,
                 label='95% confidence interval')

    # plot posterior
    y_sample = gp.sample_y(X_test,4)
    plt.plot(X_test,y_sample,lw=1)
    plt.scatter(X[:,0],y,c='r',s=50,zorder=10,edgecolor=(0,0,0))
    plt.title("Posterior (kernel:%s)\n Log-Likelihood: %3f"
             % (gp.kernel_, gp.log_marginal_likelihood(gp.kernel_.theta)),
              fontsize=14)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: can you add your code and the data ? what exactly is the 5D input ?

Comment: I have updated the data and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special in using multiple inputs for GP regression, apart maybe that, for the anisotropic case, you must provide explicitly the relevant arguments in the kernel definition.

Here is a simple example for dummy 5D data, as yours, and an isotropic RBF kernel:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import numpy as np

# dummy data:
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=20, n_features=5, n_targets=1)
X.shape
# (20, 5)

kernel = RBF(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-1, 10.0))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gp.fit(X, y)
# GaussianProcessRegressor(alpha=1e-10, copy_X_train=True,
#             kernel=RBF((length_scale=1), n_restarts_optimizer=0,
#             normalize_y=False, optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b',
#             random_state=None)
```

UPDATE: In the *anisotropic* case, you should define the different parameters explicitly in the kernel; here is an example definition for the RBF kernel and a **2D** variable:

```
kernel = RBF(length_scale=[1.0, 2.0], length_scale_bounds=[(1e-1, 10.0), (1e-2, 1.0)])
```

Extend analogously for the 5D case.

Comment: Does the kernel change?

Comment: @ArvindShankar what exactly do you mean? It works as-is in the example I have shown, for the isotropic case (i.e. all 5 inputs share the same kernel parameters)

Comment: look at this link. The author changes the kernel to accommodate 2D. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6657

Comment: Is it possible to explain isotrpy and anisotropic case? I am not able to get it

Comment: @ArvindShankar this is the general *anisotropic* case, not necessary for the isotropic one. See update

Comment: @ArvindShankar that's another, wholly different question, that has to do with the theory behind GP's. Given your question, the point is that you can just use 5D inputs without changing anything else in your code, which arguably is what your question was about...

Comment: I am sorry, for asking you multiple questions. Are you trying to generate random data in this line, "X, y = make_regression(n_samples=20, n_features=5, n_targets=1)". In my case, I would have to pass the original data that I have. Or rather my original inputs?

Comment: @ArvindShankar yes, I needed some 5D input data to demonstrate the case, and you didn't provide any in your question. You just replace it with your data of shape (1600, 5).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176837/discussion-between-arvind-shankar-and-desertnaut).